# PIL Jpg images merging killed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a script where I take multiple jpg images, resize them, merge them and create a pdf. After a while the script is killed automatically in the middle of execution.

Is there any way I can avoid this? I suspect it is a memory issue:

```
 imageList = sorted(glob.glob(root+files+'/*.jpg'))
pdf = glob.glob(root+"*/"+"*.pdf")


noImages = len(imageList)
factorL = 0.25
factorP = 0.5
im_list = []
start = time.time()
for i in range(0, noImages):
    print("Pages: ", i+1,"/", noImages,")",imageList[i])

    image = Image.open(imageList[i])


    height = image.height
    width = image.width

    if(height> width):
        bigSide = height
        newWidth = int(image.width*factorP)
        newHeight = int(image.height*factorP)
    else:
        bigSide = width
        newWidth = int(image.width*factorL)
        newHeight = int(image.height*factorL)

   
    image = image.resize(size = (newWidth, newHeight))
    if(i == 0):
        im1 = image
    else:
        im_list.append(image)



name = root.split(" ")[0]
#path where pdfs are to be stored
namePath = rootPDF+pdf_id+".pdf"
im1.save(namePath, "PDF" ,quality=40, save_all=True, append_images=im_list)

while not os.path.exists(namePath):
    time.sleep(1)
    
if(pdf!=[]):
    pdf.append(namePath)
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for f in pdf:
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(f), 'rb')
    with open(namePath, 'wb') as new_file:
        merger.write(new_file)

with open('pdfcreated_log.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(pdf_id)

#os.rename(root+pdf_id, root+"/_"+pdf_id)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code is storing all of the images in a list before creating the output file. That could very well cause a memory problem. You may have to recast the program to add one image to the PDF, close it, and then reopen it to add the next image, and so on. Or a compromise solution to add them in batches rather than all at once.

Comment: Is there a way to create the pdf with the first image and then keep on appending images to it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using, so you would have to check out the documentation to see how to do it.

Comment: Before investing time in modifying your code, look at the images you want to put in the PDF, and add up how many bytes they take in total: in the folder where they are, do `dir *.jpg`. If your program is running out of memory creating the list of images, it is unlikely that you can write a program to put them in a PDF, even one by one. All PDF libraries I know of keep the whole PDF in memory, because a PDF is not a linear structure. If the images won't fit in memory in a list, the resulting PDF won't either. An image in a PDF takes about 2× as much memory because it is represented in hex.