# Wordpress python script stops before completing

Tags: python, wordpress

I have a python script that is run from wordpress and is stopping midway since it takes quite some time to execute (it is creating a pdf from a number of images). No errors are thrown but the pdf is incomplete. Is it a memory issue please?

Comment: There are no details on which to base an answer here - please edit the question to show (not describe) what’s happening and whatever info you have as to what’s happening.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72714055/pil-jpg-images-merging-killed. If so please edit _that_ question to add enough details for someone to answer it (and delete this question).